# Template or .tpl file problem in my website

Tags: php, http, templates, smarty

My website has everything ok . Just one problem is that , when i want to change my website template to a new template then every option is working properly except "contact" option . After changing old template with new template , when i click on " contact" option then it shows `HTTP ERROR 500` error . How can i fix this ?

Comment: Look in your logs to see what the actual error is, then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your cache template dir (delete all files in this dir). By default this is *./templates_c*